# Capistrano Deploy from Remote Server

Tags: ruby, capistrano3

I'm using *Dotenv* to populate my environment when deploying and I have a deployment server that contains all the secrets.

I want to be able to do a `cap production deploy` from my localhost which triggers my deployment server to do a `cap production deploy` from itself which contains all the secrets not available from everyone's local machines.

Is there any capistrano add on gems that solves this problem? Or can someone point me in the right direction.

I was thinking of setting up a whole new stage that points to the deployment server.

Comment: is it service based secret ENV's  for production ??

Comment: Yes like different db host and aws buckets for each stage. It is set up like this for security and scaling.

Comment: @laan krynauw These should be at server it self in ENV variables , rather then keeping it on local and putting the dependency in the deployment script AND never place those in repository

Comment: Use this gem https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro and make list of all secrets and push sample file on repo application.yml.sample that will be the sample creds and place original file on server

Comment: @WishZone I already get my ENV variables in the right place with the deploy. My secrets are all in one location on my deployment server and on each deploy they're copied to the server.

Comment: From a quick scan it looks like figaro is just a replacement for dotenv and a task capistrano.

Comment: Secrets should not be copied to server while deployment , that is bad as it is vulnerable. They should be placed on server directly to keep it safe , That is the approach I am following and believe me its traditional :)

Comment: I'll do some research on the vulnerability. Thank you. Although for the mean while I'd still like this quality of life improvement :).

Answer (score 0):

Secrets should not be copied to server while deployment , that is bad as it is vulnerable and we do not change them frequently.  They should be placed on server directly to keep it safe , That is the approach I am following, we can use dontev or figaro gem to manage it